# Помогите с веб приложением на flask(товары не добавляются в базу черезе веб форму)

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-программирование, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Форма для добавления товара:

```
class AddProductForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Product name', 
                    validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)])
    description = TextAreaField('Product description', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=10)])
    picture = FileField('Update Profile Picture', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'])])
    price = IntegerField('Price', validators=[DataRequired()])
    choices = [(cat.id, cat.name) for cat in Category.query.all())]
    category_id = SelectField(label='Select category', coerce=int, choices = choices)
    submit = SubmitField('Add Product')
```

Сам шаблон в котором отображается форма:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('login') }}">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.name.label }}
    {{ form.name }} <br>
    {{ form.description.label }}
    {{ form.description }} <br>
    {{ form.picture.label }}
    {{ form.picture }} <br>
    {{ form.price.label }}
    {{ form.price }} 
    {{ form.submit }}
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

И наконец сама логика:

```
@app.route('/add_product', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_product():
    form = AddProductForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        product = Product(name=form.name.data, price=form.price.data,
            picture=save_picture(form.picture.data), description=form.description.data, category_id = form.category_id.data)
        db.session.add(product)
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template('service.html', form=form)
```

После нажатия на кнопку добавить товар не происходит вообще ничего. Запрос в браузере виснет, но товар в базу данных не добавляется именно из html формы. Если напрямую через базу данных добавить и всё в ручную прописать - добавляется, а так нет. Помогите, я перепробовал уже всё!

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, стоит поменять `url_for('login')` на `url_for('add_product')`. Во-вторых, нужно добавить атрибут `enctype="multipart/form-data"` в тег `form`.